# Ejabberd server setup

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I was trying fresh setup ejjaberd server 19.02. All thinhs went well but when i tried to run the server at last `./ejabberdctl start` i have the following error

> 

```
2020-03-17 17:55:47.301 [error] <0.482.0>@ejabberd_listener:report_socket_error:417 Failed to open socket at 1xx.1xx.xx.xx:7777 for mod_proxy65_stream: can't assign requested address
2020-03-17 1x:5x:4x.3xx [critical] <0.358.0>@gen_mod:start_module:228 Failed to start module mod_proxy65: 
{error,
    {eaddrnotavail,
        {child,undefined,
            {7777,{1xx,1xx,xx,xx},tcp},
            {ejabberd_listener,start,
                [{7777,{114,130,83,54},tcp},
                 mod_proxy65_stream,
                 [{server_host,<<"localhost">>},
                  {auth_type,anonymous},
                  {recbuf,65536},
                  {sndbuf,65536},
                  {shaper,none},
                  {ip,{1xx,1xx,xx,xx}}]]},
            transient,brutal_kill,worker,
            [ejabberd_listener]}}}
2020-03-17 17:55:47.302 [critical] <0.358.0>@gen_mod:maybe_halt_ejabberd:311 ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

ejabberd.yml file is default, i didnt touch it 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem .My domain pointing was wrong. I wrote 127.0.1.1 [domain_name].com but will be 127.0.1.1 [domain_name] . you have to make this change on `/etc/hosts/`